# Primefaces calendar date to show holidays

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

In PrimeFaces 5.1 Calendar to show specify country holiday event like Google Calendar.Is possible?

```
<p:calendar.../>
```

Comment: I guess you need to use [`p:schedule`](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml) instead (providing the days yourself).